# How to use android third party library twitter and myspace in same application?

Tags: android

I am Integration Twittor which uses signpost core 1.2 and signpost commons 4.1.2 signpost commons 4.1.1-snapshot for authorization.

But problem arises when i integrate it with MySpace app which use signpost core 1.1 sanpshot and signpost commons 4.1.1-snapshot for authorization.

it shows error
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Loauth/signpost/commonshttp/CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;

Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
What i will do prevent this problem
Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

try to change the workspace and create new project and add everything related to the project. by this the "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" will get solved.

Answer (score 0):

Hi To Integrate Both twitter and myspace in same application.

Use SocialAuth Android Library.

Here is the link

http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/

You can also integrate Facebook and Linkedin in same application.